# Native app converted from PWA taking only 12 characters for app name on Play Store and App Store

Tags: android, react-native, progressive-web-apps, bubblewrap

Recently there was a requirement where we needed to deploy an Android App(Converted from PWA using [Bubble wrap](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap)) on play store.
While creating the Android package from the PWA site, in one of the step we need to provide the name of the app and a short name. The name of the app is supposed to be shown as the text under the app icon and short name as the bubble wrap doc mentions will be shown when the device space is limited and it can not show the full app name. But it turns out the short name is shown in the home screen.
[image]

But the irony is it only allows a maximum of 12 characters. I have seen android and iOS apps having name longer than 12 characters. My requirement is to provide a name which is 20 characters long.

is it possible to anyhow provide a longer name ?  I would really appreciate if anyone has done this before and give me some pointers on this. I would be really happy to have at least some discussion around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving same name for both full and short name.
Short name has 12 characters length.

[Here is source code comment](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/blob/cc4c907a2fe98f6e128289ad6cae48e4e70396e9/packages/cli/src/lib/strings.ts#L200C1-L201C1)

```
\t- ${bold('Application name:')} the name used in most places,
\t  including the App information screen and on the Play Store.

\t- ${bold('Short name:')} an alternate name for the app, limited to
\t  12 characters, used on a device launch screen.
```